# Extract data from a long string and store into seperate variables in java

Tags: java

my string is in this format:
(notice all elements are being delimited by a space)

```
data = "row_id email year month day path"
```

so the string should look like this:

```
data ="3 email@goofy.com 2013 July 13 c:\hold_files\lisa.jpg"
```

I need to get each element in that string in following variables:

```
String sRow_id, sEmail, sYear sDay sPath;
```

does anyone have any ideas on how to do this ?

Comment: By the way, Android coding convention does not suggest to use prefix "s" for string variables, but it is typically used to indicate a static variable.

Answer (score 5):

You can split your string using [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method of `String` class, which gives you an array of `String` .

Something like this :

```
String[] splitArray = data.split("\\s+"); // for more than one spaces
String[] splitArray = data.split("\\s"); // exactly one space
```

*i need these elements in variables, not array.*

You can assign each array element to one of your variables , using simple array index.

Comment: hi, well, that wont work - because if i use split, my array will be something like this: var[0]= rowid  , var[1] = email  <-- i need these elements in variables, not array.

Comment: @FishBoy are you serious..why not do it yourself..you just have to use index..

Comment: Let's hope the path doesn't include a space (let alone two or more consecutive spaces!), and that this doesn't get localized to a language where a month name might be more than one word (I don't know which language that'd be, but I've seen stranger things...). Of course, there's String.split(String,int), but that only covers the case of the path containing spaces. That said, I give you +1.

Comment: @MichaelKjorling Absolutely correct ! We need more info from OP on that .

Comment: I've come across the situation a few times when a supposed "won't ever possibly change" turned into "we must be able to change this". It isn't pretty.

Comment: StringTokenizer or Scanner are preferred to splitting on "\\s+", as they do the same thing and are optimized for the task.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.split()` to split the String by the space delimiter

Like so:

```
data ="3 email@goofy.com 2013 July 13 c:\\hold_files\\lisa.jpg";

String[] split = data.split("\\s");
String sRow_id = split[0];
String sEmail = split[1];
String sYear = split[2];
String sDay = split[3];
String sPath = split[4];

Log.i(TAG, sRow_id + " " + sEmail + " " + sYear + " " + sDay + " " + sPath);
```

Comment: you need to use `+` in case there are more than 1 space..

Comment: yes ken, i think that worked :)

Comment: @Anirudh indeed, however the question specified that they are delimited by "a space". Which means 1. :)

Comment: @KenWolf ohh..yes indeed..

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
String data ="3 email@goofy.com 2013 July 13 c:\hold_files\lisa.jpg";
Scanner scannerInstance = new Scanner(data);
sRowID = scannerInstance.next(); 
sEmail = scannerInstance.next();
sYear = scannerInstance.next();
sDay = scannerInstance.next();
sPath = scannerInstance.next();
```

Using `split` is another way to do this, as is [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

Comment: How did you feed "data" to scannerInstance?

Comment: There is a constructor, it's listed on the link and the answer has been edited to reflect that.